# Protobuffers error adding library to android

Tags: android, maven, google-app-engine, android-studio, protocol-buffers

I have the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK plugin.xml
>       File1: /home/aaa/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.0.0.M5/4f6bda3f528c60a12e70db2e7a3feee539dcc8cd/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.0.0.M5.jar
>       File2: /home/aaa/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/kr.motd.maven/os-maven-plugin/1.2.3.Final/5467b32e1fe84f9ee2ea00a7e64128a269fb44a6/os-maven-plugin-1.2.3.Final.jar

and I get this error when I add this lite:

```
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.6
```

To the build.grandle (app) dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.google.sample.helloandroid"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 17
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "hello-android-jni"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.6'
}
```

How can I solve the problem? I need to add the protobuf to use in the project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.6'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf should be added at `buildscript` level, it should be in the build.gradle that its in your root folder not inside `/app`, also please ensure youre using gradle 2.12+ and  Java7:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.6'
  }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

then under your app/build.gradle do this:

```
android {
     packagingOptions {
          pickFirst 'plugin.xml'
     }
}
```

Comment: but this way I'm getting Error:(9, 26) error: package com.google.protobuf does not exist

Comment: any idea why this problem?

Comment: Also see the official example in: https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#latest-version

Comment: I see the exchange but I'm still getting the mistake

Comment: I add build.grandle from the root application

Comment: try adding  `mavenCentral()` it in the `allprojects {}` block

Comment: I add, but I get the problem, I'm missing something but what can be?

Comment: try now, to see if its a packaging problem

Comment: but I don't have any file with that name :S I have a clean project with a jni connection nothing more... just this alteration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106640/discussion-between-jmr-and-eefret).